# Game ignores simulated input

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make an AI to play tetris on Puyo Puyo Tetris. I'm using [this library](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=inputsimulator)
to send inputs to the game. However, the game seems to completely ignore inputs sent using this library, though inputs are received by other applications. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it, and are there any other libraries that would work?

Comment: It's happening because game developers try to detect and ignore computer-generated input, because that is a sign of cheating. Asking for a library is off topic, however.

Comment: I think google released the games they used to train their Neural Networks - including all the modifications needed to do so the AI could work with it. As Raymond said, ingoring non-human input is a very common anti-cheat measure.